# How to retrieve the NAME and ID attibute values that ASP.NET MVC would use when building an HTML control for a model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I want to make an applet able to post data on a controller that is supposed to get data from a form. My problem is that I don't know how to programmatically retrieve the NAME and ID attributes ASP.NET MVC would use for building HTML controls for each propetry (so that I can feed them to the applet to use them for posting).

How can I retrieve the NAME and ID attibute values that APS.NET MVC would use when building an HTML control for a model variable ( e.g. when using `@Html.TextAreaFor()`)?

**EDIT:**
I guess that I only need the NAME attribute. It seems that I could get this using reflection but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an html helper like this to get the html name of a model property:

```
public static string FullHtmlNameFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        if (htmlHelper == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("htmlHelper"); }
        if (expression == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("expression"); }

        return htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Now there are also the

```
Html.FieldNameFor()
Html.FieldIdFor()
```